# Illustrator isn't allowing me to select part of a graphic

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, selections

I'm trying to edit a text based image in Illustrator CC but parts of the text are not allowing me to edit or even select them. even clicking Select All doesn't work. has anyone had this problem? any solutions?

Answer (score 13):

Most probably, some of your objects are locked. Try <kbd>Object > Unlock All</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) to unlock everthing that's been locked.

You can also use the `Layers` palette to unlock objects or groups. Every object and group has a an 'eye' icon and an empty square in front of its entry in this palette. The eye is for visibility—click it to hide the object, and click the empty area where the eye was to show it again.

The extra empty area is for the 'lock' icon: click it to lock an object, and click the lock icon to unlock it again:

[image: lock icons in illustrator layers palette]

Comment: I have unlocked every item (because the option to unlock all is in grey, not an option to select) and yet still I cannot select anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @Anna That's going to be nigh impossible to answer definitively without more information. One possibility is that you're stuck in Isolation Mode. To get out of that, use the Selection tool and double-click anywhere in the illustration. Another is that you have 'Show Edges' toggled (Ctrl/Cmd + H) and just can't see the selection lines because of that.