# Can't copy from one artboard to another (Ps CC 2015)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard, creative-cloud, cc-2015

I am trying to copy object from one artboard to another using "duplicate layer" but it seems locked. Would anybody know why I cannot move it?

Comment: Is the ayer actually locked, or are you seeing some kind of UI glitch? (See: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42484/illustrator-isnt-allowing-me-to-select-part-of-a-graphic)

Comment: If you add a screenshot of your layer setup that might help

Answer (score 1):

Under the image tab, then under mode, make sure they both have the same modes set. I usually use RGB Colour. See if they both have that setting. Then try doing it once you switch it.

Answer (score -3):

Layers (and layers groups) can't be copied. Drag and drop or duplicate (to destination) is the only way to move layers from one document to the other.

http://sivioco.com/blog/how-to-copy-layers-from-one-photoshop-document-to-another